Migration ubuntu and Windows to a new SSD
I have 2 OS (Ubuntu 22 LTS and Windows) on one ssd (256GB).
I have a installation flash-card with new Ubuntu.
I wanna upgrade ubuntu to 24 LTS and integrate new SSD.
What steps should I do?
Expecting result:

Ubuntu 24 LTS with my old home directory with user.
All old drive allocated for ubuntu and /opt on the new one.
Windows on the new drive without data loss (optional)


I would be inclined to do the following but there are other approaches:

Backup your Windows data. If you want extra safety make an image of the entire old drive.
Disconnect your old drive and connect the new drive
Install Windows on the new drive. Check it boots and restore your Windows data. When happy all is OK proceed to the next step.
Reconnect the old drive and boot it into Ubuntu. Delete the old Windows partitions. Don’t delete the esp partition.
Update Grub and test you can boot Ubuntu and Windows from grub.
Use a live environment to run GParted and resize your Ubuntu partition(s).
Boot into Windows and shrink a Windows partition to make space for a /opt partition
Boot into Ubuntu and create a partition for /opt on the new SSD. Rsync the contents of /opt to the new partition. Edit fstab to mount the new partition at /opt
Boot into a live environment. Mount the partition where the old /opt lives and delete the contents of the old /opt

You will need to make adjustments in your BIOS/UEFI to select the right device to boot as you work through this. Ubuntu installation media will give you access to a live environment; choose “Try Ubuntu”
Good luck
